# Paging Issue SP 2010 with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

Paging is not working in here, the error it says : The query expression is not supported.
Error occurs in this line:
clientContext.Load(listItems, itms => itms.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));

Could someone advise Please?

Thanks

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to return list of documents of a specific document library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="docLibaryName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Document> GetDocumentsByLibraryName(string spURL, string docLibaryName, int PageSize, int PageNumber)
    {

        List<Document> docList = new List<Document>();
        //Access the Document Library
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(spURL);
        List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibaryName);

        //Specify the Caml Query
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View Scope='Recursive'></View>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.Load(listItems, itms => itms.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        AddItemsToDocumentCollection(docList, listItems);
        return docList.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Skip` operator is not supported, as the error indicates.

There is no `Skip` operator in CAML, so there is no way for the query provider to translate that query for you.

The only paging operation supported by Sharepoint is getting the next page, not the n-th page.  You can get the next page by setting the `CamlQuery` object's `ListItemCollectionPosition` to be the `ListItemCollectionPosition` value of the `ListItemCollection` after the query is executed.  If it's null, then there is no next page.  You also need to set the `RowLimit` in the query's viewXML to determine the page size.

It'll look something like this:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http://vddp23q-5d16d1e/"))
{
    var query = new CamlQuery();
    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
    int pageSize = 10;
    query.ViewXml = string.Format(
@"<View><RowLimit Paged='true'>{0}</RowLimit></View>", pageSize);

    ListItemCollection items;
    do
    {
        items = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var item in items)
            DoStuff(item);
        query.ListItemCollectionPosition = items.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    }
    while (items.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
}
```

Side note: make sure you dispose of your `ClientContext` objects.

Comment: How could Paging can be done, using this approach? Do I need to look at some other approaches?

Comment: If it's null, then there is no next page. Thanks that's a good tip as going back after the end of the page is well impossible. At least it seems to be.